# Google map custom marker with pop-up (Info Windows) on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have customized Google Map with Custom Markers. I need to integrate **Info Windows** to each marker.

**Custom Marker** code from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Tried to integrate **Info windows** from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Here is a related question i found (but it is not exactly what i want): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059129/6191987

My code below:

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [{
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712753, -74.006081),
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713664, -74.007819),
      type: 'library'
    }];

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
    });
  }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvkk7wNQcIYXZ7S8XNG8cG-elq0QE2v3k&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

Also added JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/7g33j2kz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to put as content of your infoWindow ?

But this seems to do the trick :

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
      parking: {
        icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
      },
      library: {
        icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
      },
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [{
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712696, -74.005019),
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712753, -74.006081),
      type: 'parking'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713664, -74.007819),
      type: 'library'
    }];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "test"
    });

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    });





  }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvkk7wNQcIYXZ7S8XNG8cG-elq0QE2v3k&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqLxnyca/

Have a good day.

Comment: Great..!  How can i put a link to pop-up window? means, same like that info window? Eg: `<a href="#link">Link</a>` Can we possible to customize the pop-up?

Comment: Sure like this : https://jsfiddle.net/uqLxnyca/1/ you can find may informations on the google documentation  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: One more thing.. It seems same contents for all Markers.. Is it possible to add separate content?

Comment: Like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/pL0n6xu1/ I set the content of the info window when you click on a marker

Comment: Not like that, i need to show some custom contents for each marker.. not that `LatLng` positions

Comment: I putted the location but you can put whatever you want (I used LatLng because its different for each marker)

Comment: I just updated like this: [https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/pL0n6xu1/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/pL0n6xu1/1/) but not working..

Comment: Yes.. Great..! It is worked... [https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/pL0n6xu1/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/pL0n6xu1/2/)

Comment: Quentin Roger, Have a Great day..! Happy coding